# ASP.NET core Identity static user

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an app with ASP.NET Identity and I want to add a static Admin account that can't that will be always there and will have all privileges and rights. I don't want to store him in DB or file (so he can't be removed), only disabled in the config files. Is this possible? I may want to have more of them.

And a second and more important question is this safe to do?

My indetity config:

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: How would this admin account get authenticated?

Comment: like any other account, though Signmanager, I maybe see the solution now. The custom user store will do it, I think.

Comment: It's probably possible, with a custom derived classes where you have overridden the authentication. It is In my opinion not very safe to have a hard coded user - as it will be hard to change. Perhaps you could look at [this series of articles](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/a-better-way-to-handle-asp-net-core-authorization-six-months-on/) for some ideas on how asp.net core authorization can be implemented with a "static" admin (among other things)

Comment: @fredrik thank, I will definitely look at it. And that's why I want some way to disable him If needed.

Comment: Surely, custom stores would get you around that, but its really awful idea imho. You can add custom logic though by extending SignInManager/UserManager that will check for a specific user name (or user id/guid) and prevent deleting that specific user. If you are worry that they may delete it directly via accessing database: don't give them access. No customer should ever be allowed to do stuff directly in database, it beats all the purpose of validation and business logic done in code